# Using Angular Material classes outside Angular pages

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

We are rebuilding our web application and have chosen to use Angular as frontend framework and Google Material as main style concept because it is simple and popular.

Most of our pages will be part of Angular application but some will be not. We want to use the same classes/styles and theme at any page of our application and avoid code duplication.

The main question is: how to use Material Design classes from Angular Material toolkit on pages without Angular? We've not found complete Angular Material CSS documentation to simply attach CSS link with library and our theme to "static" page.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe try searching here: node_modules\@angular\material\_theming.scss

Comment: Attach the angular-material.css in your HTML pages...  for e.g. index.html... everything outside the Angular App as well as your Angular App will be using this css file...

Comment: when you use angular-materials in your angular project and include the CSS file of your angular material in your angular project you can include that CSS file in any other html and the browser cache the CSS file on first call (when angular resolve the angular-material CSS) and I think it is not duplication.

Comment: Thanks you for this simple answer, but can you provide a link to the CSS classes documentation of Angular Material? We have ready page layout on MDL using, for example, grid system and have to "translate" Material Design Lite styles to Angular Material styles but cannot find detailed docs about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no documentation on

> Using Angular Material classes outside Angular pages

because Angular Material is not intended to be consumed/used as a style/script 'toolkit'. It is a component library for the Angular application framework platform. It is implemented by using custom components, directives, etc. and not by applying classes to standard HTML.

For example, an Angular Material form field is not created with:

```
<div class="mat-form-field">...</div>
```

it is created with:

```
<mat-form-field>...</mat-form-field>
```

which of course won't work outside Angular.

That being said, style is style, CSS is CSS, and it can be applied to anything as long as it is imported into the page. So `<div class="mat-form-field">...</div>` will probably do something, but it is unlikely that it will do what you might want it to do - results will vary widely. The main point is that `class="mat-form-field"` is not designed to work other than when produced by using `<mat-form-field>`. Ditto for all of the rest of library (there might be a few exceptions to this for specific features with certain components - not sure - but the component documentation would note this).

Officially documenting how to do something requires that it be designed and supported for that use. That obviously isn't the case here, so that's why there isn't any official documentation.

An exception to this is Angular Material's typography classes which can be used as classes for regular HTML, and accordingly is [documented](https://material.angular.io/guide/typography).

Comment: Hello (react  dev here), I'm facing the same issue and this is very helpful however I also found this https://material.io/components/dialogs/web#alert-dialog I suppose that's unusable and all the events are meant to be caught only via angular right?

Comment: @syd619 - the MDC components are a library of web components. See https://material.io/resources/tutorials#web and https://www.webcomponents.org/introduction. They are unrelated to Angular Material except in that they are both implementations of Material Design. But they are like Angular Material in that they are a combination of both custom elements and custom style, so they also do not work simply by applying style classes to standard HTML elements.