# How to load angular material css

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I have basic navigation and two components.

Component1 uses MatTable, but Component2 pure HTML table with material css classes:

```
<table class="mat-table mat-elevation-z8">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="mat-row">
      <td class="mat-cell">
```

When I navigate to Component1 and then to Component2 everything is nice.
However when I navigate to Component2 first, the some of material styling is missing, e.g. the table lines.

How to correctly use material css in angular without using material components

Comment: Where did you include the Angular Material theme import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to correctly use material css in angular without using material components

The short answer is that you cannot do this. For a more thorough explanation, see [Using Angular Material classes outside Angular pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54438158/using-angular-material-classes-outside-angular-pages/54449885#54449885).

To reiterate the points of that post, the main thing you need to understand is that `<table mat-table>` is an Angular Component, whereas `<table class="mat-table">` is just a `<table>` with a class. When you use the component, you get all of the encapsulated style that belongs to the component only, not just style defined in the global style sheet for the class "mat-table". Of course, as stated in the link, style is style, css is just css, so using the material classes will do something, but it won't do everything you probably want.

Comment: So what should I do, if I need custom functionality that isn't supported by Angular Material?

Comment: I don't really understand that question. You should use Angular Material components the way they are supposed to be used. Angular Material is not a style class library. Why can't you use `<table mat-table>` instead of `<table class="mat-table">`?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to import material theme to your app, in my opinion is adding to your (src/styles.scss, considering you are using SCSS preprocessor):

```css
// material theming
@import '../node_modules/@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();
@import 'my-theme';

// create the default theme
@include angular-material-theme($my-theme);
```

then, include your own theme (my-theme.scss):

```css
$my-primary: mat-palette($mat-blue_gray, 800);
$my-accent: mat-palette($mat-green, 400);
$my-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);

$my-theme: mat-light-theme($my-primary, $my-accent, $my-warn);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only disgusting workaround I found is including an empty mat-table before or after your custom table.

```
<table mat-table>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="workaround">
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">workaround</td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['workaround'];"></tr>
</table>

<table class="mat-table mat-elevation-z8">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="mat-row">
      <td class="mat-cell">
...
```

This way, it will include all the required CSS.